# How can i return a dynamic json/xml object in my WCF webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic

I have several webservices working as an API for my database, built in C#, WCF 4, returning json and xml format. Currently they work with specific Typed objects, but i want to be able to return dynamic data. Somewhat like what the [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html) does, you can send in the "fields" variable, and only get the specified datafields back.

I'm thinking i could probably use the Dynamic type for this somehow, but I havn't used it much and have no idea where to begin. Ideally if someone could point me to a project where this has been implemented i could learn from there, or if someone has an idea on how to implement this.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this or not, but if not it could be a good start: [WCF Serialization of DLR dynamic types](https://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/)

Answer (score 0):

You can return `IDictionary`. The JSON serializer will pick it up and serialize correctly.

Comment: This still only works with concrete types. It won't handle, for example, IDictionary<string,object>.